# Error System.NullReferenceException while assigning List<T> to a property C#

Tags: c#, list, nullreferenceexception

This is not something I don't know what is `NullRefrenceException`. There is some uncertain situation where I was getting the error.

I'm trying to assign values to properties of some classes.

Here are my classes.

```
// These classes are in EmailProcess namspace
public class ActionedEmailReport
{
    public Message Message { get; set; }
    public string SaveToSentItems { get; set; }
}

public class ToRecipient
{
    public EmailObject.EmailAddress EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public Body Body { get; set; }
    public List<ToRecipient> ToRecipients { get; set; }
}

public class Body
{
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

// Below class in EmailObject namespace.
namespace EmailObject
{
   public class EmailAddress
   {
      public string Address { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Here is my code to assign values to the properties of the classes.

```
public void EmailProcessing(string recepeint)
{
   ActionedEmailReport actionedReport = new ActionedEmailReport();
   List<ToRecipient>toRecipient = new List<ToRecipient>();
   EmailObject.EmailAddress emailAddress= new EmailObject.EmailAddress();
   emailAddress.Address = recepeint;
   toRecipient.Add(new ToRecipient()
{
   EmailAddress=emailAddress
});

   // I'm getting error on the below line.    
   actionedReport.Message.ToRecipients = toRecipient;
   actionedReport.Message.Body.Content = "Hello";
   actionedReport.Message.Body.ContentType = "Text";
   actionedReport.SaveToSentItems = "True";
   actionedReport.Message.Subject = "Demo Email"
}
```

On the line `actionedReport.Message.ToRecipients = toRec;` I am getting error that

> System.NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have checked inputs properly and sure that I am assigning some value to `toRecipient` then why I am getting this error. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: It certainly looks like `actionedReport.Message` hasn't been assigned, but running under a debugger will be able to confirm this.

Comment: `toRecipient` might not be null, but what about `Message` or `ToRecipients`? When you build a new `ActionedEmailReport`, are the objects that it contains instantiated?

Comment: Check the question which yours is a duplicate of. Specifically the accepted answer's "Class Instances" and "Indirect" parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Message` property in `ActionedEmailReport` is not being instantiated. You need to add a constructor to your `ActionedEmailReport` and new up the `Message` property.
You will probably need to do the same with the `Body` property in the `Message` class too.

Comment: Cool! this trick worked. Thanks a lot.